# How to click on link in an Android WebView with Appium?

Tags: android, selenium, android-webview, appium

Windows 7, Android app running on AVD API 18 with Appium 1.4.0 and Python 2.7

I am writing tests for Android app that displays some content in an `android.webkit.WebView`. There is a link ("YOUR CHOICES") that I must click on in my test but I don't know how to do that. UIAutomator nor Appium inspector can see inside the WebView.
[image]

Comment: Have the same problem. I'm not sure if Appium GUI can show locators of elements in WebView. Now I get them programatically - switch to webView and invoke getPageSource() method... It return me webpage which I run in browser (on PC) and look for elements in selenium.

Comment: This works too. I already got the source with getPageSource() but then the other answer appeared which worked too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what app you're trying to automate, but

Have you tried **remote-debugging via chrome devtools?**

There you have the ability to explicitly [debug and inspect webviews](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews).

But you could also try this **simple way**:

1) switch to the webview context

```
driver.context("WEBVIEW")
```

2) and then just look for the linktext

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("YOUR CHOICES"));
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it worked like this:
self.driver.switch_to.context('WEBVIEW')
self.driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("YOUR CHOICES")

Comment: @potato300 happy to be of help. Glad you found the right commands for your preferred language.